# Totally stuck with bootstrap menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/34Lf1mke/

[image]

But the title and menu should always be fixed at the top.

But no matter what I try, if one thing works another things breaks.
Either:
-the width/padding get's incorrect
-the Foo content thing gets behind other things
-the responsiveness breaks
-things disappear
-etc. etc.
-affix behaves really strange.

It's like a recursive problem.

I also tried it with bootstap-4 but that made it even worse.

My latest attempt is totally broke.
https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/Lwwe7o1j/

Normally, I would ask a question more specific but I can't see clear anymore.
Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Here is a starting point:

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="title" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">THE<br/>TITLE</div>  
  <div class="clearfix">
  </div>

  <div id="menu" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">MENU<br/>item1<br/>item2<br/>item3</div>

  <div class="content col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
    <div>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar</div>
    <div>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham</div>
    <div>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam</div>
    <div>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar</div>
    <div>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham</div>
    <div>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam</div>
    <div>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar</div>
    <div>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham</div>
    <div>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam</div>
    <div>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar</div>
    <div>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham</div>
    <div>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam</div>
    <div>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar</div>
    <div>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham</div>
    <div>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam</div>
    <div>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo<br/>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar<br/>Bar</div>
    <div>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham<br/>Ham</div>
    <div>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam<br/>Jam</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Edit, to go in more detail:

On a mobile it should be something like this:
(purple is title, blue is menu, orange is content).
[image]

When scrolling the title and menu should not scrol.
This is an example of having scrolled a bit.

[image]

For a bigger screen it would be like this:

[image]

scrolled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use the code written below. I think this code will perfectly work for you. If the code don't work for you. Mention the problem in the comment below.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Affix Vertical Side Menu</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative;
      font-family: roboto;
  }
  .affix{
   top: 0px;
   width: 23%;
  }
  p{
   font-size: 18px ! important;
  }

  #title1 {color: #000; background-color:  orange; padding: 20px;}
  #title2 {color: #000; background-color:  orange; padding: 20px;}
  #title3 {color: #000; background-color:  orange; padding: 20px;}
  #title {background-color: aqua;}
#menu {background-color: aquamarine;}
.content {background-color: orange;}
.nav-stacked li a{
 color: black ! important;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="15">
<div class="container-fluid"><!--Content fluid starts-->
  <div class="row"><!--Row starts-->
    <nav class="col-lg-3" id="myScrollspy"><!--Column for (Vertical side menu Here >>>)-->
<div class="panel panel-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="70">

    <div class="panel-heading" id="title">THE TITLE</div><!--Your Title-->
    <div class="panel-body" id="menu"> <!--Panel Body starts--> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"> 
        <li><a href="#title1">Title 1</a></li><!--Menu title1-->
        <li><a href="#title2">Title 2</a></li><!--Menu title1-->
        <li><a href="#title3">Title 3</a></li><!--Menu title1-->   
    </ul>
    </div><!--Panel Body ends-->
  </div>
 
    </nav><!--Nav & Column ends-->
    <div class="col-lg-9"><!--Column starts your content Here >>>-->

      <div id="title1"><!--Title 1 content starts-->   
        <h1 class="text-center">Title 1</h1>
        <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>

     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
      </div><!--Title 1 content ends-->   

      <div id="title2"> <!--Title 2 content starts-->   
        <h1 class="text-center">Title 2</h1>
           <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
      </div><!--Title 2 content ends-->

      <div id="title3"> <!--Title 3 content starts-->        
        <h1 class="text-center">Title  3</h1>
          <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
      </div><!--Title 3 content ends-->   
          
      
    </div><!--Column content ends-->
  </div><!--Row ends-->
</div><!--Content fluid ends-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort. Really appreciatie it. The title and menu should always be fixed at the top. So they should scroll along the page. And there should never be something on the right side of the title div.

Comment: What actually you mean. Add any screen shot of what you actually want. You Question is not clear. What is that something that should be on the right side of the title div. The above code works for you or not. If code works you upvote my code and put tick button

Comment: I added some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit ----**
**This is the code you are asking for. Use this code it will perfectly work for you.

 Happy Coding :-)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Affix Vertical Side Menu</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative;
      font-family: roboto;
  }
  .affix{
   top: 70px;
   width: 23%;
  }
  p{
   font-size: 18px ! important;
  }

  #title1 {color: #000; background-color:  orange; padding: 20px;}
  #title2 {color: #000; background-color:  orange; padding: 20px;}
  #title3 {color: #000; background-color:  orange; padding: 20px;}
  #title {background-color: aqua;}
#menu {background-color: aquamarine;}
.content {background-color: orange;}
.navbar-default{
 background-color: purple ! important;
}
.nav-stacked li a{
 color: black ! important;
}
.navbar-brand{
 color: white ! important;
}
.navbar-nav li a{
 color: white ! important;
}
/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
body{
 padding-top: 70px;
}
.affix{
   top: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 100;
  }
}
/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
body{
 padding-top: 70px;
}
.affix{
   top: 70px;
   width: 23%;
  }
}
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="15">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  

<div class="container-fluid"><!--Content fluid starts-->
  <div class="row"><!--Row starts-->
    <nav class="col-lg-3" id="myScrollspy"><!--Column for (Vertical side menu Here >>>)-->
<div class="panel panel-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">

    <div class="panel-heading" id="title">THE TITLE</div><!--Your Title-->
    <div class="panel-body" id="menu"> <!--Panel Body starts--> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"> 
        <li><a href="#title1">Title 1</a></li><!--Menu title1-->
        <li><a href="#title2">Title 2</a></li><!--Menu title1-->
        <li><a href="#title3">Title 3</a></li><!--Menu title1-->   
    </ul>
    </div><!--Panel Body ends-->
  </div>
 
    </nav><!--Nav & Column ends-->
    <div class="col-lg-9"><!--Column starts your content Here >>>-->

      <div id="title1"><!--Title 1 content starts-->   
        <h1 class="text-center">Title 1</h1>
        <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>

     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
      </div><!--Title 1 content ends-->   

      <div id="title2"> <!--Title 2 content starts-->   
        <h1 class="text-center">Title 2</h1>
           <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
      </div><!--Title 2 content ends-->

      <div id="title3"> <!--Title 3 content starts-->        
        <h1 class="text-center">Title  3</h1>
          <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
     <p> Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
      Foo Foo Foo Foo
      Bar Bar Bar Bar
      Ham Ham Ham Ham
      Jam Jam Jam Jam
  </p>
      </div><!--Title 3 content ends-->   
          
      
    </div><!--Column content ends-->
  </div><!--Row ends-->
</div><!--Content fluid ends-->

</body>
</html>
```